# svn use from default path /usr/bin instead of /opt/local/bin

Tags: macos, svn, unix

I have macports installed on my mac. One of the macports programs I installed must have needed svn. I have svn installed through macports. This is fine. I don't mind having that installed. However, I'd prefer having svn refer to the one that is in /usr/bin. Now, I like have both /usr/bin and /opt/local/bin in my .profile file. I plan to keep it like that.

Can I create a symbolic link that points to /usr/bin and is called svn.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have svn in two locations:

1. /usr/bin/svn
2. /opt/local/bin/svn

If you create symbolic links for svn in /opt/local/bin with the same name, it will effectively remove the binaries from the macport.

or else you have to create symbolic link with different name which is not very useful.

How about having an alias that points to the one you want to use:

> alias svn=/usr/bin/svn

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make sure /usr/bin is first in your path?

Comment: if you are using macports for all other things like say python then you want /opt/local/bin first in the path.